# Current through Resistor, Diode and Capacitor in Series

Tags: capacitor, diodes, simulation

I have the following circuit consisting of a Resistor, a Diode and a Capacitor all connected in Series. (The exact values are not relevant to me).

Ultimately I would like to have a formula describing the Voltage across the capacitor as a function of time.
A formula describing the current as a function of time would also suffice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTuXeE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we ignore the diode (e.g.: replacing it with a short) the problem becomes trivial in the form of:
$$V_{\text{cap}}(t) = V_1 \cdot \left(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right) \qquad \tau = RC$$
This is following [this capacitor charging description](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capdis.html) and simply applying \$C = \frac{Q}{V}\$ to solve for the voltage.

However adding the diode complicates things a bit.
The current in the circuit is no longer only dependent on the capacitor and cannot be modeled as \$I = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}\$.

The current through a diode can be modeled as
$$I = I_{\text{S}} \left(e^{\frac{V_D}{nV_T}} - 1\right)$$
with \$I_{\text{S}}\$ being the saturation current, \$V_D\$ the voltage drop across the diode, \$n\$ the quality factor and \$V_T\$ the thermal voltage.

I am unsure whether this is the correct approach to modeling the current through a diode and how I would go about combining the model of the diode with the capacitor (and resistor).

---

LTSPice Simulation:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 176 32 32 32
WIRE 176 48 176 32
WIRE 32 144 32 32
WIRE 176 160 176 128
WIRE 176 256 176 224
WIRE 32 336 32 224
WIRE 176 336 176 320
WIRE 176 336 32 336
WIRE 176 368 176 336
FLAG 176 368 0
SYMBOL res 160 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL cap 160 256 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMATTR SpiceLine V=2.5 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0
SYMBOL voltage 32 128 R0
WINDOW 3 -37 53 Right 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL diode 160 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
TEXT -66 366 Left 2 !.tran 1m startup
```

Simulation Results:

[image: LTSPice Simulation for a R, D and C in series]

- V(n001) is the Source Voltage
- V(n002) is past the resistor above the diode
- V(n003) is past the diode, above the capacitor
- I(C1) is the current in the system

All voltages are in respect to ground

Comment: You're doomed. You won't find a closed-form equation for Vd vs I. (I think that's what you're looking for.) You should consider that there are no diode data sheets with Is or n, so you wouldn't find a useful equation even  you did find an expression to put them in. Spice solves the problem with numerical methods. An old version I know used Newton-Raphson iteration. That should be enough for whatever it is you need. Spice solves for Vc using reasonable values for the diode, but the result still isn't any more accurate than an experienced guess.

Comment: @stretch Unfortunately not as elegant as I'd have hoped for, but still very much useful knowing it's not possible analytically. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use a simpler diode model. A constant 0.7V forward voltage model is practical.